# Getting an error about the default constructor and I don't know why - C++

Tags: c++, constructor, g++

I was just making a simple C++ program for practice, and I keep getting the same error, which is saying that I don't have a default constructor. However, I have tried explicitly declaring a default constructor, and I still get the exact same error. I don't understand what the problem is. Here is the error I am getting from GNU C++ Compiler:

sorting.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sorting.cpp:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘Time::Time()’
sorting.h:12: note: candidates are: Time::Time(int, int)
sorting.h:7: note:                 Time::Time(const Time&)

And here is the code:
**sorting.cpp**

```
#include "sorting.h"

int main()
{
    Time* courses = new Time[3];
    courses[1].setTime(9,30);
    courses[2].setTime(10,30);
    courses[3].setTime(12,0);
    Course this_year(3, courses);
    this_year.printTimes();
    delete [] courses;

    return 0;
}
```

**sorting.h**:
    #include <`iostream>`

```
using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
        int                 hours;
        int                 minutes;
public:
                    Time();
        Time(int h = 0, int m = 0) ;
        void                setTime(int h, int m) ;
        void                printTime();
};

class Course
{
private:
        int                 period_count;
        Time*               periods;
public:
        Course(int count, ...);
        void                printTimes();
};

Time::()
{
};

Time::Time(int h, int m)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
};

void Time::setTime(int h, int m)
{
    hours = h;
    minutes = m;
    return;
};

void Time::printTime()
{
    cout << hours << ":" << minutes;
    return;
}

Course::Course(int count, Time* the_times)
{
    period_count = count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
            periods[i] = the_times[i];
    }
}

void Course::printTimes()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
            periods[i].printTime();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: -1: The op appears to have edited this and fixed the problem by adding a default constructor.

Comment: You have another problem with arrays being zero based. The indexes 1, 2, and 3 should really be 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: The code you posted won't produce that error message. Could you reduce the complexity of your sample to a single file, with a single class, that still demonstrates the error?

Comment: Fixing the code without marking the changes is bad manners as it confuses everybody who didn't see the original question.

Comment: Its giving me this error message, even with the added default constructor, I suppose it must be my computer then. Oh right, thanks for pointing that out Bo.

Comment: @Evan, it gives a different message with the changes you made.  It now gives an error about ambiguity which is pretty easy to figure out and if your question had the real error message you'd have a good, correct answer by now.

Comment: @Evan - Now you have two constructors that can be called without giving any parameters. The compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

Comment: Even with all the changes and removing the ambiguity, I am still getting the exact same error. It's got to be my computer then. I tried doing this on another computer, with all the fixes and now I am getting: 
In file included from sorting.cpp:1:
sorting.h:67:2: warning: no newline at end of file
sorting.cpp:14:2: warning: no newline at end of file // I went in and added a new line to the file, and it seems to work. But it still doesn't work on my original computer for some reason. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time I guess.

Answer (score 1):

`Time* courses = new Time[3];` creates an array of 3 Time objects - which requires Time to have a default constructor (as the objects need to be constructed when the array is created).

If you don't want to create a default constructor for `Time` *consider* using `std::vector`, and insert the necessary objects one at a time into the vector.

Comment: Which is a good reason to use std::vector, which places no such requirement on the contained class.

Comment: I've updated the question slightly, explicitly declaring a default constructor. And on compiling this code, I am still getting the same error. Suggestions?

Comment: `Time:()` looks to be a syntax error (he says, not having touched C++ for years...  :)).

Comment: That was a mistype by me, because I didn't want to paste the entire block in again due to the weird formatting. So that is not the problem. I would have gotten an additional error if I compiled with that in there as well.

Comment: Don't you need `Time::Time()`, rather than just `Time::()`?

Comment: Once again, another typo. It's Time::Time() in the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, The compiler cannot identify your `Time(int, int)` constructor as a default constructor (that is needed when using `new Time[3]`), although the ints have default arguments. Just try adding a real default constructor to `Time`.

Answer (score 0):

I got two errors, both different from yours.

Using g++ 4.4.5, the variable count was undefined in Course::printTimes(), and the prototype for the Course constructor's ... didn't match the declaration.  No problem with the Time() constructor, tho.

Comment: Oh oops. Well I tried fixing this stuff, but I'm still getting the same error. I suspect it has something to do with my computer. I'm running Mac OS X 10.5 and just compiling using g++ out of terminal.

Comment: Try removing the default parameters for Time(int h = 0, int m = 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
Time:() 
{
};
```

should be

```
Time::Time() 
 : hours(0), minutes(0)
{
}
```

or some equivalent